# losing cookies when navigating to a new page with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, cookies, navigation

I'm using Selenium with Python to log onto a page, and then immediately jump to another page in the same tab. I need the credentials of the page to be saved, but what happens is they are lost when I move to the new page.

I have tried 2 things - one is to save the cookies after the input.send_keys(keys.ENTER) command in the code below using pickle.dump, and then loading the same cookies after the new page loads. The other is to just load a Firefox profile I made after saving the cookies.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pickle
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxProfile

profile = FirefoxProfile("C:\\Users\\ace\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\l4piuit9.ace")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get("https://forums.the-elite.net/index.php?action=login")

# #handle the form data and log in by forcing an enter
inputElement1 = driver.find_element_by_name("cookieneverexp").click()
inputElement2 = driver.find_element_by_name("user")
inputElement2.send_keys('REMOVED')
inputElement3 = driver.find_element_by_name("passwrd")
inputElement3.send_keys('REMOVED')
inputElement3.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

#save the cookies, they don't transfer over when navigating to a new page
#pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("elite.pkl", "wb"))

#new page / poll
driver.get("https://forums.the-elite.net/index.php?action=votelog;topic=22504")

#get the cookies
#cookies = pickle.load(open("elite.pkl", "rb"))
#for cookie in cookies:
#    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

None of these seem to do anything. I thought maybe a delay would be required so I included an implicit_wait of 10s but that did not seem to make a difference.

What is the cause of this and how can I resolve it?

Comment: why do you have all web element with same variable name ?

Comment: Good point, I just copied the previous one and forgot to edit the name. But my issue still persists. Edited my code.

Comment: I can see two-two web elements for username and password field , would you be more specific which one you want to use for login ?

Comment: Do you mean two for each? I'm not sure I understand your question. Both are needed for the login.

Comment: there is two way to login , one via providing username and password on top right side ,and second is to provide username and password in middle of web page.now my question is which one you want to select for login ?

Comment: Oh. The top-one.

Comment: Can't reproduce this problem. No issues maintaining session moving from one page to the next. Consider just removing the saving/loading of cookies. Trying to load old cookies will probably invalidate your session.

Comment: what did you do to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
import pickle

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'D:/Automation/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://forums.the-elite.net/index.php?action=login")

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)

browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, -200)") 

username = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form#guest_form input[name='user']")))
username.send_keys('Removed')

password = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form#guest_form input[name='passwrd']")))
password.send_keys('Removed')
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

def save_cookie(browser, path):
    with open(path, 'wb') as filehandler:
        pickle.dump(browser.get_cookies(), filehandler)

def load_cookie(browser, path):
     with open(path, 'rb') as cookiesfile:
         cookies = pickle.load(cookiesfile)
         for cookie in cookies:
             driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Make sure after loading the cookies you are **refreshing the page**.

Comment: But this does not have the behavior I intended it to have. I want to switch to the other page while keeping the login details. With this I have to manually enter that link as opposed the browser automatically going there.

Comment: new page is in same domain ? you can load the cookies after that. just make sure you have to refresh the page.

Comment: when you tried with profile , then what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same domain. [Here is my adjusted code](https://hastebin.com/ozedopupap.py) (see line 22-25, the rest is just using Firefox because I don't have chromedriver). this gives me a "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine" error.

Comment: I didn't get any error using the profile. It would just not save the session. It did once or twice.. but not all the time so I'm not sure what the problem could be.